# How to make decimal appear on lollipop graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code for a lollipop graph. For the bars with a value of 4, I would like the data label to read 4.00. How can I modify my code for this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
#par(oma=c(0,0,2,0))

df_graph2 <- data.frame(
parameters = c("REED 530: Process & Acquisition of Language and Reading",
             "EDU 603: Principles and Practices of Research ",
             'PHEC 604: Human Movement and Physical Activity for the Elementary Classroom', 
             'REED 532: Reading Materials',
             'EDUC 606: Developmental Theory & Experiential Growth ',
             'SPED 551: Adapting Instruction in Diverse Classrooms',
             'EDUC 661: Mathematics: Curriculum, Instruction & Assessment',
             'EDUC 662: Science and Health: Curriculum, Instruction & Assessment',
             'REED 531: Reading/Literacy Instruction'
             ),
values <- c(4.00,3.88,4.00,4.00,4.00,4.00, 3.75, 3.13, 4.00))
df_graph2 %>%
ggplot() + aes(x=parameters, y=values) +
geom_segment( aes(x=parameters, xend=parameters, y=0, yend=values), color="gray36", size=2) 
+
geom_point( color="goldenrod2", size=4.2, alpha=0.9) +
geom_text(aes(label = paste(values)), hjust = -.3,size=3.8,family="Arial") + 
expand_limits(y = 6)+
theme_light() +
coord_flip() +
theme(
plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 4, 1.1, "cm"),
panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black', size = 12, hjust = 1),
panel.border = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
axis.title.x = element_blank(),
axis.title.y = element_blank(),
axis.text.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by formatting via e.g. `scales::number(value, accuracy = .01`:

Note: I wrapped your long labels using `str_wrap` because otherwise the numbers did not show up in the reprex.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_graph2 <- data.frame(
  parameters = c("REED 530: Process & Acquisition of Language and Reading",
                 "EDU 603: Principles and Practices of Research ",
                 'PHEC 604: Human Movement and Physical Activity for the Elementary Classroom', 
                 'REED 532: Reading Materials',
                 'EDUC 606: Developmental Theory & Experiential Growth ',
                 'SPED 551: Adapting Instruction in Diverse Classrooms',
                 'EDUC 661: Mathematics: Curriculum, Instruction & Assessment',
                 'EDUC 662: Science and Health: Curriculum, Instruction & Assessment',
                 'REED 531: Reading/Literacy Instruction'
  ),
  values <- c(4.00,3.88,4.00,4.00,4.00,4.00, 3.75, 3.13, 4.00))
df_graph2 %>%
  mutate(parameters = stringr::str_wrap(parameters, width = 40)) %>% 
  ggplot() + aes(x=parameters, y=values) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=parameters, xend=parameters, y=0, yend=values), color="gray36", size=2) +
  geom_point( color="goldenrod2", size=4.2, alpha=0.9) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::number(values, accuracy = .01)), hjust = -.3,size=3.8,family="Arial") + 
  expand_limits(y = 6)+
  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 4, 1.1, "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black', size = 12, hjust = 1),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]